# How to search a directory that's excluded from my project in PyCharm?

Tags: search, ide, pycharm

I have a "cachegen" folder where a lot of files that my program generates are kept. Usually, when searching for code, I want to omit this directory since it's all derivative of my actual code - so I've excluded it from my project.

In this case, though, there seems to be a problem with the cached result, and I want to search through the cachegen directory to find it. However, if I select the cachegen directory, PyCharm says "Directory [cachegen] is not found" - even though the path most definitely exists.

Comment: I do not observe this problem in PyCharm 4.0.4